Why is "gangster" sometimes pronounced more like "gankster"?
As Wiktionary notes, in American English the word gangster can be pronounced either as /ˈɡæŋ.stɚ/ (straightforwardly "gang" + "-ster") or as /ˈɡæŋk.stɚ/ ("gankster"). For the pronunciation I'm talking about, see this video at 10:15, this video at 6:30, this video at 42:10, this video at 20:05, this video at 16:50, and this video at 34:03, though I'm not actually sure whether I'm  hearing all of those correctly.
Where does this pronunciation come from?

This is not a duplicate. /ŋ/ and /s/ are not homorganic, so there is not as much motivation for affrication as there is in /ns/.

@Nardog: The answers to both linked questions cover epenthesis between a nasal and a non-homorganic fricative, such as /ŋ/ and /s/. From Araucaria's answer: "When we move from a nasal consonant /m, n, ŋ/ to a /f, θ, s/ or /ʃ/, we often accidentally make a /p, t/ or /k/ between them." It then cites a blog post by John Wells that refers to "when ANY nasal is followed by ANY voiceless fricative, though only in certain syllabification environments." From Rayan Khan's answer: "length is almost always pronounced lengkth, with an epenthetic k between the nasal [ŋ] and the oral fricative [θ]"

See language, wrong of me, ng in any word, long ass, winningG

@StuartF None of those involve epenthetic [k].

@herisson I'm intrigued by the term 'oral fricative'. What's a non-oral fricative?

@Araucaria-Him I noticed your (excellent, as usual) answer to the duplicate actually used gangster as an example--somehow I missed it while trying to look this up before posting the question.

@alphabet 'Twas a good question, but another great mind pipped you to it :)

@Araucaria Oral means not nasal, i.e. the velopharyngeal port is closed.

@Araucaria-Him: It's not my wording, but I think it's clear the intention was to point out that the fricative is phonetically an oral consonant (although the nasal-oral contrast is of course not phonemic for fricatives, nasal fricatives are phonetically possible, as they apparently can occur as a speech error: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/17549507.2021.1891285)
